# inserting 1000 image in oracle 11gr2 with blob data type using sql / sql developer

Tags: database, oracle, image, blob

i'm trying to insert 1000 images located on my "E" partition on my hard drive
the images named as (img1.jpg, img2.jpg,.....)
colud this be done using insert statement in a loop with counter changing the img(counter).jpg

```
     begin
        for i in 1 .. 1000 loop

 "insert Statement"

        end loop;
        commit;
    end;
```

Comment: It would be much easier to use sqlldr to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle how to load a picture into a blob column using sqlldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079338/oracle-how-to-load-a-picture-into-a-blob-column-using-sqlldr)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @thatjeffsmith A much easier option would be to use sqlldr. And you can create a .ctl file as below

```
options (bindsize 10000)
load data
BADFILE 'E:\IMAGES\sqlldrbad1.bad'  
DISCARDFILE 'E:\IMAGES\sqlldrdiscard1.DIS' 
append
into table IMAGES
(
  image,
  table_name constant "IMAGES",
)
```

And then to load the data

```
for %F in (E:\IMAGES\*.jpg) do sqlldr username/password@db control=contr.ctl data=%F
```

You can also check the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079338/oracle-how-to-load-a-picture-into-a-blob-column-using-sqlldr)

Else you can use UTL_FILE like the example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258762/how-do-i-use-oracle-utl-file-to-write-an-image-clob)

Comment: I can't fully understand you in my case, I have images located in "E:\clone"  named (img1.jpg , img2.jpg , .... ) ,i want to insert it to a blob column named "photo" in a table named "jpg" .

Comment: can you offer more explanation or sources, please

Comment: I suggested that instead of writing an insert statement like the one you have been trying to, if you can load the data/images into the table using sqlldr as was even suggested by others. I just posted a sqlldr .ctl file snippet. And how to use the .ctl file to load all your image files from your local drive to the database.

Comment: Also if you can check the links I provided in my answer it would give you a better picture how to use the sqlldr or UTL_FILE

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort I'll try it and give you a feedback